# Cant Install Windows XP on netbook,restarts in an infinite loop

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, bios, reboot

This problem was annoying me for a couple of days now

I have a really low end netbook and windows 7 lags like hell,so i decided to install XP

The problem is this:

I boot from the usb,and select the first part of the installation of windows(Since im using the wintoflash method),then the blue screen of windows setup appears,everything seems fine until i reach the "Windows setup is starting" part,then my screen turns black and shows the classic Underscore flashing once and restarting inmediatly
I tried booting from hirens boot and using "Mini xp" but that ends up in the same result

My bios settings are this: -Secure boot:disabled -CSM support:enabled -uefi boot:disabled -legacy boot:enabled -boot priority:legacy first

On advanced options: -Xhci mode:disabled -EHCI controller enabled(I dont have any more options,my bios is very basic)And the usb is set to boot first

Comment: Legacy Boot and CSM are the samething...

Comment: Installing XP on a modern computer is often a serious challenge, one that may ultimately prove futile. The immediate problem is that you likely have an SATA drive which XP does not natively support. But that is likely to be only the beginning of  your problems. Obtaining device drivers for your netbook is likely going to be a big problem. The install media won't have them and it is doubtful if the netbook manufacturer will either. Check with the manufacturer to see if it is supported. Usually Windows 7 runs at least as well as XP if the computer meets the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As LMiller7 commented, the likely problem is with mix-up of hard disk drivers, in some difference in logical addressing scheme between BIOS driver and XP driver. It is difficult to say exactly what is at fault. It could be some odd partition (various recover partitions, secure partition, other garbage). I would suggest to try several things:

1. Take the drive to a different PC, and use Win7+ utility diskpart.exe to completely clean the drive (google the usage). The drive must be initialized as "MBR drive".
2. Try to disable in BIOS anything related to AHCI (SATA) controller, it should be "IDE Compatibility" exclusively, if possible.
3. When XP is in setup of hard disk, always use full re-partitioning and re-formatting of the drive, to clean up any "safety" partitions.

You need to find a configuration (partitioning/formatting) of your drive that is common between your super-modern UEFI/BIOS and legacy XP-defined formats. You need a good luck with that.